# Can I use a SSL certificate to to clickonce code signing?

Tags: clickonce

As the title says, the only thing is I dont have a private key file
that Brian Noyes says I need in this blog post.

http://www.softinsight.com/bnoyes/2006/06/23/ManagingClickOncePublisherCertificateFiles.aspx

I have a SSL certificate for a website on my server and I want to clickonce a windows app to the server. That is why I want to use the SSL cert.

Malcolm

Answer (score 4):

[No.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172240(VS.80).aspx)

> For ClickOnce applications, you must
>   have an Authenticode certificate that
>   is valid for code signing; if you
>   attempt to sign a ClickOnce
>   application with another type of
>   certificate, such as a digital e-mail
>   certificate, it will not work